# Interactive features of JasperReports without involving JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a few reports that I developed, compiling jrxmls using Java, filling reports and displaying report output in IFrame (Jsp). Even though I used table components I can't see any interactive features in report, Question I have:

Are there any other alternatives that I can acheive interactive features like Sorting, Filtering etc.., without using JasperReports Server?

Comment: You can use sorting and filtering in generated by JasperReports *XLS* files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same question was asked on the [jaspersoft community site](http://community.jaspersoft.com//questions/1033026/how-can-achieve-interactive-features-jasper-reports-without-jasper-server). Duplicating my answer here:

> There is a sample -
>   **webapp-repo**(https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/tree/master/jasperreports/demo/samples/webapp-repo)
>   that comes with the jasperreports project - in which most of the
>   interactive features that JasperReports Server exposes can be achieved
>   in a servlet container.
>
> To run the sample:
>
> 1. Download the **jasperreports** project source files(https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports). If you want a
>      stable version pick the latest tag
> 2. Install **apache ant** if you don't have it
> 3. Build the main project(the root of the <jasperreports-project> that contains a build.xml) with: **ant alljars**
> 4. Navigate to <jasperreports-project>/demo/samples/webapp-repo and create the application war with: **ant war**
> 5. Deploy the **jasperreports.war** to a servlet container like Tomcat