# How to generate a sortable and filterable html table in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

Does JasperReports provide an option for adding a filter or a sort option for any column header, so the rows can be sorted afterwards by the user?

Here is the HTML, generated by JasperReports:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            text-decoration: none
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body text="#000000" link="#000000" alink="#000000" vlink="#000000">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center">

                <a name="JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1"></a>
                <table class="jrPage" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="empty-cells: show; width: 842px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white;">
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:0">
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                        <td style="width:270px"></td>
                        <td style="width:266px"></td>
                        <td style="width:266px"></td>
                        <td style="width:20px"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:20px">
                        <td colspan="5">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:40px">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3" style="text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 22px; line-height: 1.2578125;">This is a table</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="3" data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #F0F8FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Header</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td class="jrcolHeader" data-coluuid="7242ebd3-b548-460d-9c66-9ee60ceebaf6" data-cellid="0_2003453457" data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" data-colidx="0" style="background-color: #BFE1FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2578125;">First column</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="jrcolHeader" data-coluuid="edca3b2a-92b0-41c1-a59e-f950d4298796" data-cellid="1_1564905786" data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" data-colidx="1" style="background-color: #BFE1FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Second column</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="jrcolHeader" data-coluuid="a7d4d7fb-7988-404d-9519-8b975fb1b21a" data-cellid="2_670858537" data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" data-colidx="2" style="background-color: #BFE1FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.2578125;">Third column</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">1</span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">5</span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">avc</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #BFE1FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">2</span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #BFE1FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">6</span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #BFE1FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">asdf</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:30px">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #F0F8FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">3</span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #F0F8FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">7</span>
                        </td>
                        <td data-tableuuid="f7b58cff-1413-4762-bdb7-ec233a690c28" style="background-color: #F0F8FF; border: 1px solid #000000; text-indent: 0px;  vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-family: 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000; font-size: 10px; line-height: 1.2578125;">a4df</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top" style="height:385px">
                        <td colspan="5">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

However I dind't find that option in the report tool yet...

Can it maybe done afterwards?

Comment: JasperReports can inject custom HTML headers when it generates an HTML report. Inside the header you can [implement JavaScript](http://www.allmyscripts.com/Table_Sort/) that allows arbitrary column sorting. If the amount of data exceeds that which can be reasonably displayed on a single page, then you'll have to look at other solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by: "JasperReports can inject custom HTML headers"?

Comment: And what about filtering?

Comment: I also tried that js thing.. But that is really right corrosive...

Comment: Ok, I've asked a new Question, since I'm really not familiar with JavaScript or HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083437/how-to-integrate-javascript-sort-and-filter-option-into-a-html-table-that-is-gen

Comment: Where are you going to deploy this report.?In jasper server if you are using table component to generate report then it allows you to sort and filter option directly. You do not have to do anything.

Comment: No, this report will not be deployed in jasper server...

Comment: I would suggest you to check datatable jquery plugin. I might help you.

Comment: If you're interested in a Java-based solution, the `webapp-repo` sample that ships with JasperReports project might be a starting point, but you would have to build on top of that. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185202/interactive-features-of-jasperreports-without-involving-jasperreports-server/40301749#40301749).